# Is possible to have a wildcard that has a value of a string that has spacings (laravel, php)

Tags: php, laravel, wildcard

I have a wildcard in my routefile but now I have the problem that the wildcard in the url looks like this: `Friday,%205.%20August` (should be: `Friday, 20. August`). He is now returning 404 because I think that wildcards only can provide a single string without any spacings. Is this true and if yes how to fix it?

Route:

```
Route::get('/{date}', [WebScraper::class, 'date']);
```

Comment: Friday,%205.%20August  is actually Friday, 5. August when decoded (your example is confusing) could you maybe explain in more detail what exactly are you expecting and if this is an API route or web route?

Comment: **Friday,%205.%20August** = **Friday, 5. August**

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the date as base64, and decoding the date in controller, and passe it as parameter not as a route like that:

Change route daclaration

```
Route::get('/date/{date}', [WebScraper::class, 'date']);
```

Decode the date in controller like that :

```
base64_decode($date)
```